# How to set django project on apache Centos 7

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have created a django project on Centos7 and now I'm trying to make it work on apache web server. But in apache error log I see this errors:

```
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930780 2018] [:error] mod_wsgi (pid=26121): Target WSGI script '/he/django/myshop/myshop/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930821 2018] [:error] mod_wsgi (pid=26121): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/he/django/myshop/myshop/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930842 2018] [:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930864 2018] [:error]   File "/he/django/myshop/myshop/wsgi.py", line 28, in <module>
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930922 2018] [:error]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Apr 23 07:01:02.930947 2018] [:error] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

My project path is `/he/django/myshop/`.

I havn't changed my default `/he/django/myshop/myshop/`**wsgi.py** file, so it looks like this:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myshop.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My `/etc/httpd/conf.d/htmltest.psina.com.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName  185.201.8.84
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /he/sites/htmltest.psina.com/htdocs/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/htmltest.psina.com-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/htmltest.psina.com-access.log combined
  WSGIScriptAlias / /he/django/myshop/myshop/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /he/django/myshop

<Directory "/he/sites/htmltest.psina.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/he/django/myshop/myshop">
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

Firstly I've created .conf file for simple html page to check if apache was workig and everything was OK (that is why I have `/he/sites/htmltest.psina.com/htdocs/` in my config).

I guess that I have problems whit diffrent python versions becouse I've installed django for python3.4 but I'm not sure that this is the main reason of the error.

Comment: you need install apache package "mod-wsgi-py3"

Comment: I've tried to do this and I got this error - No package mod-wsgi-py3 available.

Comment: yum install python35u-mod_wsgi

Comment: Same - No package python35u-mod_wsgi available.

Comment: can you use "yum search"

Comment: install manually https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-archive-x86_64/python35u-mod_wsgi-4.5.7-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Warning: No matches found for: python35u-mod_wsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI the above error required **"python35u-mod_wsgi"**

can you install manually from this link [install python35u-mod_wsgi](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-archive-x86_64/python35u-mod_wsgi-4.5.7-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html)